# Divide a mismatch dataframe into two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Following is my code wherein I see a mismatch data frame being generated and the mismatch records are shown one below the other. I wanted mismatch from one table and mismatch from another table to be segregated and shown in two data frames. One data frame of Table 1 mismatched records and one data frame of another table mismatched records.

```
import pandas as pd

def merge_dataframes(left_dataframe, left_dataframe_suffix, right_dataframe, right_dataframe_suffix, how, key_columns, indicator):
    """
    Joins both the dataframes on the key columns.

    :param left_dataframe: Dataframe on the left side of the join
    :param left_dataframe_suffix: Suffix for the left_dataframe columns after join
    :param right_dataframe: Dataframe on the right side of the join
    :param right_dataframe_suffix: Suffix for the right_dataframe columns after join
    :param how: Type of join Valid values: {‘left’, ‘right’, ‘outer’, ‘inner’, ‘cross’}, default value: ‘inner’
    :param key_columns: Columns based on which join should happen
    :param indicator:  Boolean. If True, adds a '_merge' column specifying whether a record belonged to 'both', or the 'left_only' dataframe or 'right_only dataframe'
    :return: Joint dataframes
    """
    comparison_df = left_dataframe.merge(right_dataframe,
                                       indicator=indicator,
                                       how=how,
                                       on=key_columns,
                                       suffixes=(left_dataframe_suffix, right_dataframe_suffix))
    return comparison_df

raw = pd.DataFrame({'EntityID': ['Appple', 'Banana', 'Mango'],
                    'Date': [10, 20, 30], 'Val': [10, 30, 15]})

# create data_frame2 by creating a dictionary
# in which values are stored as list
bob = pd.DataFrame({'EntityID': ['Appple', 'Banana', 'Mango'],
                    'Date': [10, 20, 30], 'Val': [100, 200, 15]})

match = raw.merge(bob, how='inner', indicator=False)

#print(match.to_string(index=False))
mismatch=pd.concat([raw, bob]).drop_duplicates(keep=False).to_string(index=False)
print(mismatch)
```

The output being shown is as follows.

```
EntityID  Date  Val
  Appple    10   10
  Banana    20   30
  Appple    10  100
  Banana    20  200
```

My expected output is

```
Mismatch raw          Mismatch bob
EntityID Date Val  EntityID Date Val
Apple    10   10   Apple    10   100
Banana   20   30   Banana   20   200
```

Is there any way in Pandas to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the options would be to use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), then [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) (*without merging*) :

```
mismatch = (pd.concat([raw, bob], keys=["Mismatch raw", "Mismatch bob"])
                .drop_duplicates(keep=False).unstack(0)
                .swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)
                .to_string(index=False)
           )
```

Output :
​

```
print(mismatch)
​
Mismatch raw               Mismatch bob              
         Val EntityID Date          Val EntityID Date
          10   Appple   10          100   Appple   10
          30   Banana   20          200   Banana   20
```

Comment: How should I convert then this to dataframe? I am getting empty dataframe using mismatch=pd.Dataframe

Comment: Remove the last chain `to_string(index=False` and then `mismatch` will be a `pd.DataFrame`.